# How do I turn off caffeinate if I want to allow my machine to sleep normally?

Tags: macos, sleep

I often use `caffeinate` to ensure that tasks on my OS X systems run to completion without interruption, and would like to be able to disable `caffeinate` to allow normal sleep once my tasks have completed.

Is there a way to turn off all running `caffeinate` processes?

Answer (score 1):

`killall caffeinate`

or if you just want to set it for a specific time…

`caffeinate -t 144000 &`  [in seconds]

Personally, if I want the machine to stay awake without affecting my normal sleep/wake behaviour, I just use a hot corner

Prefs > Mission Control > Hot Corners…

[image]

Then as I wander away from the machine I just push the cursor into the top left corner & it will stay awake til I get back.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the system to go back to original sleep settings after a certain task is finished **automatically**, use

```
caffeinate -i /path/to/binaryoftheapp
```

For example:

```
caffeinate -i /Applications/Safari.app/Resources/MacOS/Safari
```

For simplicity, e.g. iTunes

```
caffeinate -i `ps -o command \`pgrep -f iTunes\`|sed -n 2p`
```

Replace `iTunes` with the name of your app/process. It's case-sensitive.